# Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131904 Caml Query

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, caml-query

I'm trying to execute a query on a custom list.  I'm receiving a generic error that isn't helping me track down the problem.

Error Message:

```
Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131904
```

Stacktrace:

```
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponseStream(Stream responseStream)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponse()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ExecuteQueryToServer(ChunkStringBuilder sb)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ExecuteQuery()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRuntimeContext.ExecuteQuery()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()
```

Relevant Code:

```
var timeHoursAgo = DateTime.Now.AddHours(ModifiedHours * -1);

string query = Camlex.Query().Where(
    x => (string)x["IsAccessGranted"] == "Yes" &&
    (DateTime)x["Modified"] >= timeHoursAgo)
    .ToString();

var caml = new CamlQuery();
caml.ViewXml = string.Format("<View>{0}</View>", query);
```

Which produces a caml query like the following:

```
<View><Query>
  <Where>
    <And>
      <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name="IsAccessGranted" />
        <Value Type="Text">Yes</Value>
      </Eq>
      <Geq>
        <FieldRef Name="Modified" />
        <Value Type="DateTime">2016-11-07T11:15:52Z</Value>
      </Geq>
    </And>
  </Where>
</Query></View>
```

What are some causes of this error I should look for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found that multiple people have received the same error when using incorrect datatypes.

So, after verifying the data types of the fields being queried directly in the Caml query, I noticed IsAccessGranted is a Yes/No field which is more of a boolean type field than a string.  After modifying the query as follows:

```
string query = Camlex.Query().Where(
                    x => (int)x["IsAccessGranted"] == 1 &&
                    (DateTime)x["Modified"] >= timeHoursAgo)
                    .ToString();
```

Which produced the following caml:

```
<View><Query>
  <Where>
    <And>
      <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name="IsAccessGranted" />
        <Value Type="Integer">1</Value>
      </Eq>
      <Geq>
        <FieldRef Name="Modified" />
        <Value Type="DateTime">2016-11-07T11:22:47Z</Value>
      </Geq>
    </And>
  </Where>
</Query></View>
```

The error no longer occurs as I'm treating the Yes/No field as boolean integer values.  Bottom line, this error appears to occur often when data types are not handled correctly.